# How add a timer in System.Diagnostic for WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have enabled tracing in a WCF service. Here is the system.diagnostics section :

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
      <listeners>
         <add name="messages"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="d:\wcflog\messages.svclog" />
        </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging
         logEntireMessage="true"
         logMalformedMessages="false"
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
         maxMessagesToLog="3000"
         maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In my trace, I wish a timer for observe performance. Is it possible ?

Best regards

Comment: You can refer to this link, the link contains timer information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Hi, i want just modify web.config not source project.

Comment: You can enable Performance Counters in WCF. For more information about Enabling Performance Counters, please refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/performance-counters/

Comment: What do you mean by saying `observe performance`? Do you want to see how long does services take to return response or something?